# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, azure-web-app-service, passport.js

I am working with an application with React Js on the frontend and node Express with Passport Js to authenticate users on the backend, both uploaded as azure app.

When I try to login from the frontend I get the error:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.azurewebsites.net/Login' from origin 'https://frontend.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.*

The cors configuration in the backend is:

```
  cors({
    origin: 'https://frontend.azurewebsites.net',
    credentials: true,
  }),
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: config.TOKEN_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }),
);
app.use(cookieParser(config.TOKEN_SECRET));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./passportConfig')(passport);
```

The request in the frontend is:

```
Axios({
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        username: this.state.user,
        password: this.state.password,
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "https://backend.azurewebsites.net/Login",
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch(errors => {
          console.log(errors);
      })
```

I have tried to fix the problem by setting the headers as many answers indicate but the problem persists. The azure CORS are disabled.

Note:

When I enable CORS for everyone

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

And I run the frontend on my local machine, configuring the proxy in package.json, the login with passport works correctly:

`"proxy": "https://backend.azurewebsites.net/",`

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like its your preflight request that is failing the access control checks. Maybe try putting your cors config inside of app.options('*',cors(......)) like that

Comment: I tried that solution but the problem persists. 

const corsConfig = {
  origin: 'https://frontend.azurewebsites.net',
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.options('*', cors(corsConfig));

Answer (score -1):

Origin should be an array, not a string.

```
origin: ['https://frontend.azurewebsites.net']
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Origin needs to be a string, not an array. An arrow of origins will result in failure.